# How to plot on browser by using javascript library propel

Tags: javascript, machine-learning

I want to run official example (http://propelml.org/), but browser console warns:

> `plot: no output handler.`

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Hello, propel!</title>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/propel@3.3.1"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <script>
    const { grad, linspace, plot } = propel;

    f = x => x.tanh();
    x = linspace(-4, 4, 200);
    plot(x, f(x),
        x, grad(f)(x),
        x, grad(grad(f))(x),
        x, grad(grad(grad(f)))(x),
        x, grad(grad(grad(grad(f))))(x));
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

What is output handler?

Comment: One more warning is showing up :

`unreachable code after return statement`

Answer (score 0):

[image]

It is just a warning and is coming from here.

One more warning is showing up :

`unreachable code after return statement`

Read more about it here

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Errors/Stmt_after_return

Answer (score 0):

From what I see, the output handler is thing, that allows rendering of a graph, either to a browser window or to NodeJS console?? perhaps. As it says on the webpage: *" ... In the browser it utilizes WebGL through  deeplearn.js  and on Node it uses TensorFlow's  C API."*

So wanna make a fancy graph? I guess you would need to dig more into coding